# Is there a way to change the MySQL Database Engine with Doctrine Migrations

Tags: mysql, migration, doctrine, innodb

does anyone know a way to write a Doctrine migration to change the Table Engine of a MySQL Database from MyISAM to InnoDB? Can this be managed via Migrations or do I have to this the old way via SQL-Statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only create, rename or delete a table with doctrine migrations.
You will have to do this the old fashioned way :)

Check the [Doctrine Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en#writing-migration-classes:available-operations).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate the 2.0 version of [Doctrine Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/introduction/en). It would not be compatible with migrations from Doctrine 1.2, but you can use it on any database, without having to use the Doctrine 2 ORM.

Anyway, using this version, it's as simple as:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=INNODB');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it via migrations (I'm using doctrine 1.2):

```
public function up()
{
  $q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
  $q->execute("ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE = MyISAM");
}
```